# bootstrap-sass 3.3.3 glyphicons showing as rectangles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap styling is working but glyphicons are showing up as: [].

I am using the bootstrap-sass gem with rails

Comment: First, we need an example of your code. Second, i'm pretty sure this is because your css can't find the fonts directory. If you look at the console it might show that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by updating the sass version.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
```

Use this link instead of local css file.